# Image doesn't show up?

Tags: android, google-signin

[image]I want to use  the avatar view using the https://github.com/TangoAgency/avatar-view   to display the user's profile image as soon as the user is logged in(the sign-in is done using the Google Sign-In Api for Android). I request the values as soon as the sign-in is complete and pass it to the next activity using intent.PutExtra().

I then retrieve the values and use them to load the users image. Here is an image of the snippet in the MenuActivity that does this. Rather than my profile image showing up, a placeholder that displays the first letter of my name is shown in the avatar view.

Comment: Your logic in that if block is broken. If `personPhotoUrl` is null, it'll continue to then call `isEmpty()` on a null object. Change `||` to `&&`.

Comment: As stated, change your || to &&

You can see isEmpty is being highlighted - If you hover over it, you'll get a hint that basically says this might cause a NullPointer. Always listen to the compiler! If it's giving you hints, you've got code you can improve.

Comment: That didn't work. I'm going to dig deeper into the api information to find out what is returned by getPhotoUrl(). Thanks for the correction.